# Minted red box around greek characters

Tags: minted

When using Minted i get a red box around greek characters
[image: Annoying red box around greek characters]

Can this behaviour be disabled or is there a specific line that needs to be changed in the python lexer?

A minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    linenos=true,
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    frame=lines
}
\begin{document}
\section{Some code in this section}
\begin{minted}{python}
def add(α, β):
    return α + β
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of minimal working example]

edit: I am using xelatex

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: You get this behaviour, too, if you use German umlauts (ä, ö, ü). Is there a "real" solution yet?

Comment: This seems to be a feature of the underlying Pygments library (cf http://pygments.org/demo/6790720/), so you would probably need to open an issue at https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues (if there isn't one already, I haven't checked) to get this changed. From the LaTeX side of things there are probably only work-around that treat the symptom, not the disease.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This seems to be an error in the Python lexer. If you don't need `\fcolorbox` inside the `minted` environment, here's a hack:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro} % I don't have Consolas

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    linenos=true,
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    frame=lines
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\dontdofcolorbox}
\def\dontdofcolorbox{\renewcommand\fcolorbox[4][]{##4}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Some code in this section}
\begin{minted}{python}
def add(α, β):
    return α + β
\end{minted}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the patch also for `\inputminted`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.py}
def add(α, β):
    return α + β
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro} % I don't have Consolas

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    linenos=true,
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    frame=lines
}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xpatch}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\dontdofcolorbox}
\def\dontdofcolorbox{\renewcommand\fcolorbox[4][]{##4}}
\xpatchcmd{\inputminted}{\minted@fvset}{\minted@fvset\dontdofcolorbox}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mintinline}{\minted@fvset}{\minted@fvset\dontdofcolorbox}{}{} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401250/
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Some code in this section}
\begin{minted}{python}
def add(α, β):
    return α + β
\end{minted}

\inputminted{python}{\jobname.py}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This hack seems to work fine for my minimal example but when i use it in conjunction with
    `\inputminted`
I still run in to problems.

Comment: ![input minted causing problems](http://imgur.com/mmWhSPF)

Comment: @KimPetersen Patch for `\inputminted` added. I used `filecontents`  just to make the example self-contained.

Comment: I tried to understand that code, but i wasn't able to :-( . Could provide me someone please a sample to stop hightlight errors in Minted Inline? I will be very thankful.

Comment: @IvoLooser The code simply disables `\fcolorbox` inside `minted` snippets.

Comment: It would be nice to have this also include the \mintinline patch from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401250/2066: `\xpatchcmd{\mintinline}{\minted@fvset}{\minted@fvset\dontdofcolorbox}{}{}`

Comment: @JasonGross Yes, it would be good, thanks for noting and for pointing to the patch.

Comment: Some stylings like `perldoc` seem to use `\colorbox` to mark errors. By using `\renewcommand{\colorbox}[3][]{#3}` you can override those colorboxes.

Comment: I rejected an edit suggesting `\makeatletter{}` and `\makeatother{}` to keep ChkTeX quiet. Sorry: if ChkTeX can't cope with standard constructions, it's *its* fault and I'm not adding useless, misleading and wrong braces in order to keep it happy.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you try to use a minted style that does not higlight `\PYG{err}`

```
\usemintedstyle{xcode}
```

Of course if your red boxes was generated because of some `\PYG{err}`

Comment: This is the best answer. I would suggest also mentioning that styles can be defined for individual instances instead of globally if you normally want syntax highlighting. For example, I was just editing a book on C which states, “The form `'abc'` is officialy undefined.” I typeset it using `\mintinline[style=xcode]{C}{'abc'}` to avoid the red boxes around the single-ticks.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness and since I can't comment yet:

The hack in the Answer by egreg can also be applied to the command `\mintinline` by

```
\xpatchcmd{\mintinline}{\minted@fvset}{\minted@fvset\dontdofcolorbox}{}{}
```

Greetings

Comment: Why re-adding the code when egreg already provided the same solution for the inline variant?

Answer (score 3):

This usually works for julia code, where the `@` would have a red box around it

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{julia}
|@|. a .+ b
\end{minted}
```

If you use `|` in your code, you can change the escape character, e.g.

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=??]{julia}
?@?. a .+ b
\end{minted}
```

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me without forcing me to change colour scheme, as it also prevents the text changing colour for these sorts of symbols which seems to happen in addition to the box.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but couldn't disable error highlighting for all minted environments. And I came up with the following modified version of @egreg that worked for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro} % I don't have Consolas

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{
    linenos=true,
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    frame=lines
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{noerr}{\dontdofcolorbox}
\def\dontdofcolorbox{\renewcommand\fcolorbox[4][]{##4}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{noerr}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Some code in this section}
\begin{noerr}
\begin{minted}{python}
def add(α, β):
    return α + β
\end{minted}
\end{noerr}

\end{document}
```

So instead of replacing `fcolorbox` in the `minted` environment, I create a new environment `noerr`,
in which `fcolorbox` is replaced. This way I can use the `minted` environment in the `noerr` environment to suppress the highlight but also use it outside to get the highlighting.

I currently don't have a corresponding version for `\mintinline` or `\inputminted`.

Comment: I like this answer and hope that something similar is implemented in the greatly revamped version of minted which is being worked on.

Comment: @hackerb9 I opend an Issue with a feature request on the minted github repo at <https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/374>