# How do I avoid \PYG{err} in minted with pygments when using unicode/UTF-8 input?

Tags: minted, pygments

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{\ensuremath{\to}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{coq}
Require Import Utf8.
Check Set → Set.
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

It outputs a pdf with this:

[image: output pdf]

I don't like the red box; it is an indication of an error, despite the fact that the code is valid Coq.  I say it is an error because in the `_minted-...` directory there is a file `B9B79F25159396E029D998834CEDDFB4348AD1BE427E596276BBAC3B129C03FF.pygtex` whose contents is

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{k+kn}{Require} \PYG{k+kn}{Import} \PYG{n+nn}{Utf8}\PYG{p}{.}
\PYG{n+nc}{Check} \PYG{k+kn}{Set} \PYG{err}{→} \PYG{k+kn}{Set}\PYG{o}{.}
\end{Verbatim}
```

What I expect is coloring identical to if I replace `→` with `->`:

[image: pdf good output]

The code in `538AF91E35E82BEEAFB959F2DD5440A2348AD1BE427E596276BBAC3B129C03FF.pygtex` is then

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{k+kn}{Require} \PYG{k+kn}{Import} \PYG{n+nn}{Utf8}\PYG{p}{.}
\PYG{n+nc}{Check} \PYG{k+kn}{Set} \PYG{o}{\PYGZhy{}\PYGZgt{}} \PYG{k+kn}{Set}\PYG{o}{.}
\end{Verbatim}
```

**So my question is, how do I get minted to replace `\PYG{err}` with `\PYG{o}`?**

---

If it's relevant, my version of pdflatex and pygmentize is

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdflatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6839 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2018 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.56.1; using libcurl/7.56.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.5.3; using LibreSSL 2.5.3
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 3.6802; using 3.6802
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 9.6844; using 9.6844
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 3.6833; using 3.6833
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
$ pygmentize.exe -V
Pygments version 2.0.2, (c) 2006-2014 by Georg Brandl.
```

The pdflatex log is available [on my gist](https://gist.github.com/JasonGross/6cc80af83a0793d9ed6e2f440c0b0611).  According to the MiKTeX console, I am using minted v2.5 (2017/07/19).

Comment: As http://pygments.org/demo/6790521/ shows this is a feature of the Python library used by `minted` as such this is not a LaTeX problem. https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/971/unicode-in-coq-files-marked-as-error-with and https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1395/apparent-missing-unicode-support-for-coq suggest this is known, but it doesn't seem that a fix is available.

Comment: I don't think `\newunicodechar` works with `utf8x`, as I have specifically excluded it. Indeed, if you remove the calls to `newunicodechar`, you get exactly the same output.

Comment: Huh, what's the reason for not supporting utf8x, or where's documentation explaining it?

Comment: @JasonGross `utf8x` takes a different approach towards managing UTF-8; plus, it's been unsupported for several years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no other way than disabling `\fcolorbox` inside `minted`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343506/4427

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newunicodechar{→}{\ensuremath{\to}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\dontdofcolorbox}
\def\dontdofcolorbox{\renewcommand\fcolorbox[4][]{##4}}
\xpatchcmd{\inputminted}{\minted@fvset}{\minted@fvset\dontdofcolorbox}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{coq}
Require Import Utf8.
Check Set → Set.
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I get different coloring, though.

[image]

Please, take care that `newunicodechar` doesn't work with `utf8x`; you get the arrow nonetheless because `utf8x` provides a definition for `→`.

```latex
Package newunicodechar Warning: This package only works if the document
(newunicodechar)                encoding is `utf8'.
```

Comment: Thanks!  Since I'm marking this answer as accepted, perhaps it should also mention that the error box comes from pygments and error on Unicode is not a minted thing, as per @moewe's comment?