# Minted remove red rectangles around characters

Tags: xetex, minted

I need to typeset a Perl Mason HTML template file. Unfortunately, there is no minted format for it, so I used standard HTML:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines, tabsize=2]{html}
<div class="grid_9 alpha content_collum">
    <& /Comp/component/breadcrumbs.msn, links => [
    { name => $ARGS{title} },
        ] &>

    <h1 class="cmn_header main_head_line">
        <% $ARGS{title} %>
    </h1>
</div>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I get strange red rectangles around "<&", "<" and "&" symbols sometimes:

[image]

Maybe, they are marking HTML errors. Is it possible to avoid them?

Comment: Related: [Minted red box around greek characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343506/79060)